# Nothing was returned from render when using prototype

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
class ContentLoader extends Component {

state = {
    animation: new Animated.Value(0)
}


render() {
    if (this.props.loading) {
        return (<View
            style={{
                height: 100,
                width: 100
            }}
        />);
    }
    return this.props.children;

}
}


ContentLoader.prototype = {
    primaryColor: PropTypes.string,
    secondaryColor: PropTypes.string,
    animationDuration: PropTypes.number,
    // children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
    style: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    loading: PropTypes.bool,

}
ContentLoader.defaultProps = {
    primaryColor: 'rgba(195, 191, 191, 1)',
    secondaryColor: 'rgba(218, 215, 215, 1)',
    animationDuration: 500,
    loading: true
};

export default ContentLoader;
```

When i use this in my component, I get Nothing was returned from render?
but when i comment this part

```
 ContentLoader.prototype = {
    primaryColor: PropTypes.string,
    secondaryColor: PropTypes.string,
    animationDuration: PropTypes.number,
    // children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
    style: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    loading: PropTypes.bool,
}
```

Everything works?
Any help?
Everthing works well without prop types, Or maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: can you show how you've used it?

Comment: The property you should set is called `propTypes` and not `prototype` which is something completely different.

Comment: I tried both, still same error

Comment: @JoeWarner I trimmed it down to only render() { return <Text>hi</Text> }, But stil same, when i uncomment that propTypes, everything works

Comment: @SarmadAijaz yeah its what trinx said

Comment: this.props.children is probably `undefined`

Comment: have you imported `PropTypes` at the top of your class. `style` is your required prop. Are you passing atleast `style` while using your component.

Comment: @SarmadAijaz Your code is not properly aligned. Please take some time to ask a question with properly aligned code. Also double check your code. If you only set `propTypes` on the component this should not affect rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ContentLoader.propTypes` instead of `ContentLoader.prototype`

prototype is used for adding methods to a object and isn't related to type checking.

here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ww1xyk

> https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype